# Can bound states have zero energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, scattering

Suppose a system is under the influence of a potential which vanishes at $\pm \infty$. Now we know that if the energy of the system is negative ($E<0$) then the system is in a bound state and the bound state energy spectrum is discrete. For $E>0$, the system is in scattering states (with continuous energy spectrum). My question is:

What happens at $E=0$? Can we consider it a discrete bound state or should we consider it as a scattering state and why?

Comment: Well, have you tried to see what happens when you put in $E=0$?

Comment: You mean if we put $E=0$ in the Schrodinger equation? I have a question about that, if I get a non-normalizable state then does it mean that the state is a scattering state and if it is normalizable then it is a bound state?

Comment: I have a $\delta$-function potential. So at $E=0$, the wave function is just a constant meaning it is non-normalizable.

Comment: Doesn't the delta function potential only have one bound state anyway?

Comment: Yes it has only one bound state but I was trying to see what will happen to the bound state in the limit the coupling constant (i.e. the constant that multiplies $\delta (x)$) goes to zero.

Comment: Wait, so when you say $E$ you don't mean the particle's energy?

Comment: I am sorry. I confused myself. I meant whether there exists any bound state when the particle energy goes to zero. Sorry for the confusion.